# Typescript runtime dynamic types

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm writing a library for binary message parsing. I export the following types:

```
/// Library code
export type MessageSchema = Record<string, IToken<number | [number, IToken<number> ]>;

export type Messages = Record<string, MessageSchema>;
```

An object of type `MessageTypes` will need to be dynamically modified at runtime. This in itself is not a problem, as I can just write a function that does something like this:

```
/// Library code
export function registerMessageType(messageName: string, messageCode: number, messageSchema: MessageSchema) {
    messageTypes[messageName] = messageSchema;
    /// This line isn't too important for this
    messageCodes.set(messageCode, messageName); 
}

/// Application code
registerMessageType(
    'HELLO', 
    0x00,
    {
        id: [UINT8, 4],
        timestamp: UINT32BE,
        wifiStrength: UINT16
    }
);
```

Which will allow the user to add message schemas dynamically at runtime. This could then be used later on in the parsing side of the library, doing something like this:

```
libraryName.parse(messageTypes.HELLO);
```

^ Not *exactly* this, as it's done within a streaming parser.

However, my first iteration of this (before I package it into a library) gave me very nice editor hints and tooling because all of the known message types were defined at runtime, within the same application.

All of this code is now to be extracted into a library and the beautiful editor tooling is now lost.

Is there a way to dynamically build the list of possible message types, as they're added?

Generics? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Something that you could do is ask the user to register the type as well if they want to be able to use `MessageTypes` as a type. This can be done with interface merging and module augmentation.

```js
export interface MessageTypes {}
```

```js
declare module 'your library package name' {
    interface MessageTypes {
        HELLO: typeof schema
    }
}

const schema = {
    id: [UINT8, 4],
    timestamp: UINT32BE,
    wifiStrength: UINT16
} as const;

registerMessageType('HELLO', 0x00, schema);
```

`MessageTypes` will be updated every time you register. It won't be easy to inspect since it's an interface but doing `{ [K in keyof MessageTypes]: MessageTypes[K] }` will demonstrate that your types have been added to the interface.

On top of being verbose, this prevents you from dynamically adding message types since interfaces can't be created on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

The types are erased during compiling, there is nothing you can do at runtime.

Comment: Bummer. What if the application code is Typescript? Is there no way to retain the information across the two?

Comment: There is no typescript runtime, typescript is always transformed into JS.

Comment: I know this. I'm wondering whether it's possible to have a library that is explicitly TypeScript and does *not* compile to JS until compilation of the application code?

Comment: i.e. can I import a pure typescript library?